# How to remove extra space after separator in toolbar in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx

This is my code:

```
public class NewMain1 extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        HBox root = new HBox();
        ToolBar toolbar = new ToolBar();
        toolbar.getItems().addAll(new TextField(), new Separator(), new Button("foo"), new Button("bar"));

        root.getChildren().addAll(toolbar);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

As you can see the  distance between a text field and a separator (left margin) is less then the distance between the separator and a button (right margin).

Could anyone say how to decrease right margin that right margin to be equal to the left margin using CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it using CSS. This is the solution:

```
.tool-bar > .container > .separator *.line { 
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I checked in [ScenicView](https://github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view) and the line in the separator is rendered as a region with padding of 3px in each direction, so it makes the separator 6 pixels wide.

But the way it is rendered places the actual separator line in the left of the region.

You can adjust the line rendering by adjusting the the CSS rules for the line (you can find them in `modena.css` in a jar file in your JavaFX distribution).  But modifying the CSS rules for the separator is confusing and I don't recommend it.

Instead set a margin on the node to move it to the location you want (normally I wouldn't recommend such a hack, but in this case it is appropriate IMO).

Because ToolBar is internally represented as a HBox, you can use the HBox methods to set the margin on nodes in the ToolBar.

To add additional space to the left, so the line is centered in its display do this:

```
HBox.setMargin(sep, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 2.5));
```

OR, to remove space from the right, so the line is centered in its display do this:

```
HBox.setMargin(sep, new Insets(0, -2.5, 0, 0));
```

The margin values I provided are just examples.  Adjust the values as per your requirements.

**Example Code**

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ToolBarApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        HBox root = new HBox();
        ToolBar toolbar = new ToolBar();

        Separator sep = new Separator();
        toolbar.getItems().addAll(
                new TextField(),
                sep,
                new Button("foo"),
                new Button("bar")
        );
        HBox.setMargin(sep, new Insets(0, -2.5, 0, 0));

        root.getChildren().addAll(
                toolbar
        );

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tryed using scene builder with fxml? That way you can drag the elements and set the margins between them.